# SVG to EPS convert - Pantone colors and CMYK profile

Tags: svg, imagemagick, inkscape, eps, pantone

Convert SVG file to EPS with Pantone colors and CMYK profile ?

Currently i use inkscape to convert but event with icc-color in fill attribute it do not store color as Pantone and sets color profile to RGB when desired profile is CMYK.

Any suggestions ?.
Solution must work on unix from command line.

Comment: Maybe creating ` not correct ` EPS and using GS to modify color profile and color names ?, Did anyone  try this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with open source and `CMYK` is that Adobe holds a patent, but you already found about that, i believe.  Thanks to the standardised ways that `ICC` profiles are made some open source software includes rudimentary `CMYK`.  One good example of patent problems is that after so many years `GIMP` has inherent no `CMYK` support (it only supports it through a plugin).

`Pantone` is a lot worse, [even wikipedia has a section about how pantone is strict and vague about its intellectual property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantone#Intellectual_property).  Inkscape does not support Pantone in any way, doing so would be too dangerous.  Your best bet might be to add a couple of `/Name` parameters to the objects in EPS and then add `Pantone` to them later (with a lousy script).